# detect where on the screen onTouchevent happened

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

I've got an onTouchEvent boolean on a Surfaceview, I've got openGL objects drawn on the view and I'm wondering is there anyway to detect where on the screen the onTouch happened? e.g (x,y) co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event.getX() and event.getY() assuming that you have the following method signature:

```
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
```

Answer (score 0):

when you touch the screen, you will get the that position x,y position range.
        @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

```
    // Normal touch
                                    xPosition = ev.getX();
                yPosition = ev.getY();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            {
                dx = ev.getX();
                dy = ev.getY();

                } 
        return ;
          }
```